# How do you create a simple Google Talk Client using the Twisted Words Python library?

Tags: python, twisted, xmpp, google-talk

I am interested in making a Google Talk client using Python and would like to use the Twisted libraries Words module.  I have looked at the examples, but they don't work with the current implementation of Google Talk.

Has anybody had any luck with this?  Would you mind documenting a brief tutorial?

As a simple task, I'd like to create a client/bot that tracks the Online time of my various Google Talk accounts so that I can get an aggregate number.  I figure I could friend the bot in each account and then use the XMPP presence information to keep track of the times that I can then aggregate.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also interested in this... does anyone know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

wokkel is the future of twisted words.  [metajack](http://metajack.im/) wrote a really nice [blog post](http://metajack.im/2008/09/25/an-xmpp-echo-bot-with-twisted-and-wokkel/) on getting started.

If you want a nice, functional sample project to start with, check out my [whatsup](http://github.com/dustin/whatsup) bot.

Answer (score 7):

I have written a simple Jabber bot (and thus Google talk bot) using the `xmpppy` library, which works well. The examples on [xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/) should get you started (specifically [`bot.py`](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/examples/bot.py))

As for something actually implemented in twisted.Words:

[Here](http://yoan.dosimple.ch/blog/2007/01/30/) is a simple tutorial on creating a bot that prints every received message to the local terminal (and a version that replies with the revere of the received message). To track the online time of various accounts, you would add a callback for "presences" (going online/offline/away etc are "presence changes", in Jabber terminology)

For a more complete system, [pownce-jabber-bot](http://code.google.com/p/pownce-jabber-bot/) uses twisted.words and  [wokkel](http://wokkel.ik.nu/) for the jabber interface.

[The  powncebot/__init__.py](http://code.google.com/p/pownce-jabber-bot/source/browse/trunk/powncebot/__init__.py?spec=svn15&r=15) file seems like a good place to start - it's seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking building an XMPP client in python a while ago.  I haven't gotten around to working on the project I was looking at it for.  I didn't see anything that used twisted but are a couple XMPP libraries I found.

- https://launchpad.net/python-xmpp/
- http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/
- http://pyxmpp.jajcus.net/

I also found a python program, under the GPL, that acts multi-point conference system using XMPP.

http://coders.meta.net.nz/~perry/jabber/confbot.php

Answer (score -2):

As the Twisted libs seem to be out of date, you have two choices:
Implement your own XMPP-handler or look for another library.

I would suggest working with the raw XML; XMPP is not that complicated and you are bound to learn something.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against dealing with raw XML (for an actual bot.. as an experiment, sure) - you are just reinventing any XMPP library. I imagine all the libraries should have a verbose option somewhere that will show the raw XML..