# Wokkel Resources

Tags: python, xmpp, twisted, wokkel

This isn't a technical question, however after hours of scouring google I have not found an viable examples or resources to learn the [Wokkel framework](http://wokkel.ik.nu/). I've extrapolated what I can from the source code itself, and the unit tests but still do not have a great understanding of how to implement subprotocols.

I'm working with a jabber server using almost all custom stanzas. If anyone has any resources or examples they could lend, that would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what kind of "resources" you're looking for, but there are lots of examples out there:

- http://wokkel.ik.nu/wiki/XMPPClients
- [An XMPP Echo Bot with Twisted and Wokkel](http://metajack.im/2008/09/25/an-xmpp-echo-bot-with-twisted-and-wokkel/) and [Echo Bot Part 2: Making a Component](http://metajack.im/2008/10/09/echo-bot-part-two-making-a-component/)
- [Twisted Wokkel Bot](http://thetofu.livejournal.com/73544.html)
- [Twisted / Wokkel XMPP Client Example](http://pastebin.com/QZvuxWt5)
- [XMPP-Ping Examples](http://wokkel.ik.nu/browser/doc/examples)

There are also numerous resources linked in [How do you create a simple Google Talk Client using the Twisted Words Python library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227279/how-do-you-create-a-simple-google-talk-client-using-the-twisted-words-python-libr)

If you need more help or want feedback from specialists, the relevant mailing list is [Twisted-Jabber](https://mailman.ik.nu/mailman/listinfo/twisted-jabber).

In addition, Wokkel is closely related to Twisted Words, so check out materials related to that project, especially http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/words/.

Answer (score 2):

I've started adding Sphinx-based prose documentation, along with the existing example scripts and put this up on http://wokkel.ik.nu/documentation. It also includes an API Reference generated using pydoctor.